# How to post to an internal URL in classic asp from server

Tags: asp-classic, form-post

How to post to an internal URL in classic asp from server?

- Using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP looks not work per [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290591/how-to-submit-form-data-by-using-xmlhttp-or-serverxmlhttp-object) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316451/info-do-not-send-serverxmlhttp-or-winhttp-requests-to-the-same-server)
- I cannot use Response.Redirect since I need to send http code 200 right after I receive the request
- I cannot use either Server.Execute or Server.Transfer since I want to modify Form collection before posting to destination internal URL

Thank you

Update:
I create an classic ASP endpoint to accept request from a third party. And I need to send back a response with HTTP status code 200. Then this endpoint doesn't process anything but needs to post the request to an internal endpoint for processing. Hope this clear now.

Khoi

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Lankymart sort of server side AJAX, i.e. calling ASP code that sit in the same directory in different file.

Comment: if you have already posted code 200 then your only option is to access the asp script using javascript from the browser. it's not very clear what you actually want to do though.

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to *achieve*? I.e. what end result do you desire? Because it sounds like this might be an x/y problem, i.e. you're asking how to do y because you think it's a way to achieve x, but in actual fact, there are much easier/better ways to achieve x.